# Problem using Query Analyzer to debug stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, debugging, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, query-analyzer

I am attempting to debug a stored procedure using the Debug option is SQL Query Analyzer (Version 8.00). However, the debugger run through the whole stored procedure as soon as I start and if add a break-point and try re-executing the sp, the break-point is ignored. What do I need to do to enable debugging? The server is SQL Server 2000

Answer (score 1):

It may be a security issue. Try doing some of the steps here: http://www.15seconds.com/Issue/050106.htm